# S3 RoutingRule: Redirect directory to subdomain

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, routes, amazon-route53

Let's say I want all requests to `https://example.com/api/users/1` redirected to `http://api.example.com/users/1` using a AWS S3 bucket.

**So all requests to the "directory" `api` should be redirected to the subdomain `api.example.com`**

Can somebody provide a **RoutingRule** for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the RoutingRule I ended up with:

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals>api/</KeyPrefixEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <HostName>api.example.com</HostName>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith/>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Comment: this works for anything https://example.com/api/path_etc, but what if you want to redirect https://example.com/api to https://api.example.com?

I can't get it to redirect. It ends up redirecting to

https://api.example.com/api

Comment: Yes, you'd need a more powerful solution like Nginx here.